# Projective modules over local rings are free (Matsumura's proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, proof-explanation, projective-module

I have a question about an argument from a proof in Hideyuki Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" on page 9, Theorem 2.5:

> Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring; then a projective module $M$ over $A$ is free.

The understanding problem arises in the verification of the case when $M$ is finite (as $A$-module). The proof works as follows:

Choose a minimal $A$-basis $\omega_1,...,\omega_n$ of
$M$. Take into account that "minimal" means that there cannot exist another system of generators $b_1,..., b_m \in M$ with $m < n$ and $M = \sum_{i=1} ^m A b_i$.

Define a surjective map $\varphi:F \to M$ from the free module $F = Ae_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Ae_n$ to $M$ by $\varphi(\sum a_i e_i) = \sum a_i\omega_i$. If we set $K = \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)$ then, from the minimal basis property

$$\sum a_i \omega_i =0 \Rightarrow a_i \in \mathfrak{m} \text{ for all } i. $$

Thus $K \subset \mathfrak{m}F$.  Because $M$ is projective, there exists $\psi: M \to F$ such that
$F = \psi(M)\oplus K$, and it follows that $K = \mathfrak{m}K$. (???)

On the other hand, $K$ is a quotient of $F$, therefore finite over $A$, so that $K = 0$ by Nakayama and $F = M$.

> Question: why the fact that $F = \psi(M)\oplus K$ implies that $K = \mathfrak{m}K$, more precisely why $K \subset \mathfrak{m}K$? (The other inclusion is trivial.)

Considerations: $F = \psi(M)\oplus K$ is a decomposition as $A$-modules and since $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ we obtain $\mathfrak{m} F = \mathfrak{m} \psi(M)\oplus \mathfrak{m} K$. since $K \subset \mathfrak{m}F$ it suffices to show that $\mathfrak{m} \psi(M)=0$. Why is it true?

I would like additionally to remark that I found already some other proofs but the intention of this question bases only on the understanding of the explained step in the presented proof.

Comment: What do you call a ‘minimal $A$-basis’ of $M$?

Comment: $n$ is minimal having the property that there exist $b_1,..., b_n \in M$ with $M = \sum_{i=1} ^n A b_i$. I will precise it

Comment: OK. It means their canonical basis is a basis of the $A/\mathfrak m$-vector space $M/\mathfrak m M$.

Comment: yes by Nakayama lemma

Comment: To show $K = mK$, you can use the argument in your consideration. Just intersect $0 \oplus K$ and $mF$. As this intersection is $0 \oplus mK$ and $0 \oplus K \subset mF$, we get the conclusion. By the way, $K$ is not a quotient module of $F$, but it is a submodule of $F$.

Comment: @Youngsu: but when we know that $F = \psi(M)\oplus K$ then $K$ is a quotient module, or not?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that can be done if the exact sequence splits. But $K$ inherits noetherianness from $F$ automatically.

Comment: yes that was a consequence of projectivity of $M$. a point that confuses me bit is the intersection argument applied to $0 \oplus K$ and $mF$. you claim that the result is $0 \oplus K$. I not sure but do such intersections always preserve direct sum structure? the example that I have in mind is when you have two $A$ modules $N,K$ with ranks $n,k$ and you intersect the induced direct sum $N \oplus M$ with diagonal $D$ of $A^{n+k}$ which is isomorphic to $A$. then the intersection has no more the direct sum structure. or do I confuse here something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\{\omega_1,...,\omega_n\}$ is a minimal system of generators of $M$, their images  $\{\mkern1mu\overline\omega_1,...,\overline\omega_n\}$ in $M/\mathfrak mM$ are a basis of the $A/\mathfrak m$-vector space  $M/\mathfrak mM$.

Now tensor the decomposition $F=\psi(M)\oplus K$ with $A/\mathfrak m$: you obtain
$$M/\mathfrak mM\simeq F/\mathfrak m F=\bigl(A/\mathfrak m\bigr)^n=\psi(M)/\mathfrak m\psi(M)\oplus K/\mathfrak m K\simeq M/\mathfrak mM\oplus K/\mathfrak mK$$
so $K=\mathfrak mK$. As $K$ is finitely generated, we can appeal to Nakayama again.

Comment: $M/\mathfrak mM\simeq F/\mathfrak m F$ is by an dimension argument,right? how do you get $\bigl(A/\mathfrak m\bigr)^n=\psi(M)/\mathfrak m\psi(M)\oplus K/\mathfrak m K$?

Comment: Yes, a dimension argument + Nakayama. For you second question, if I understand it well,  I use that tensor product is distributive over direct sums

Comment: yes I understand. $(A/m)^n \simeq A^n \otimes_A A/m \simeq F \otimes A/m \simeq (\psi(M)\oplus K) \otimes A/m \simeq \psi(M)/\mathfrak m\psi(M)\oplus K/\mathfrak m K$ thank you very much!

Comment: Why $K$ is finitely generated?